# Owner-draw table: detect whether actual cell is painted or hover

Tags: java, swt, tableviewer

If you hover over a table cell which is too narrow, some kind of popup occurs. How can I detect in `OwnerDrawLabelProvider.paint()` whether the (truncated) table cell is painted or the popup?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately, there seems to be no way to get this information directly from the `Event`. But we implemented following ways:

- On Windows the popup is higher than the cell (tested on Windows 7 aero theme). This means, if `event.height != event.gc.getClipping().height`, the hover is painted.
- On OS X the popup has the same size as the cell, but the `Table` has a field `drawExpansion` which is set to `true` when painting the hover. Just use reflection to read it.
- SWT on Ubuntu does not even show any hover at all...